# How does one approach a bayesian inference problem given data?

Tags: r, probability, self-study, bayesian, inference

Lets say that wa have data on x-values for successful and unsuccessful products that a company tries to develop and that we want to make bayesian inference on some parameters $\mu$ and $\gamma$, with flat priors. The probability that a product is successful is given by the equation:

$p(x)=\frac{exp((x-\mu)e^-{\gamma})}{1+exp((x-\mu)e^-{\gamma})}$

The data on the successful x-values are:

```
[1] 16.52 20.39 16.61 30.72 19.54 23.31 12.97 17.51 15.27 10.31 30.35 20.07 13.92 19.78 11.68 19.91  9.56 19.73 12.49
[20] 18.30 15.72 16.11 16.14 16.99 10.90 23.68 20.24 14.69 12.98 13.82  5.50 15.45 13.23
```

and the data on the unsuccessful x-values are:

```
 [1]  6.71  3.20  5.24  7.31 10.29  8.52  2.71  4.49 12.42  5.16  3.79  7.43  6.75 18.99  7.74 18.83 13.16  6.65  5.07
[20]  9.16  7.24  6.25 20.71 15.34 10.24  1.51  9.17  5.21  5.23 12.87 14.30  7.72  9.06  6.36  4.89 10.97  7.60 15.10
[39]  9.18  4.49  6.98 13.55 10.26 10.84  4.47 10.54 12.88 11.18 17.83 10.65  6.65  8.50 11.38  1.33  9.30  9.60  7.25
[58] 11.65 11.47  2.80 14.48  6.30  5.84 15.18  5.78
```

**Task:** Plot the data together with curves given by $p(x)$ for various
values of $\mu$ and $\gamma$. Make a conclusion about what kind of range of
values for the parameters $\mu$ and $\gamma$ might be reasonable in this model.

I have no idea were to start when approaching this problem. How does one reason or implement a strategy to make bayesian inference for the parameters $\mu$ and $\gamma$?

Comment: This question need a 'self-study' tag.

Comment: I added one! :)